# Access the Chef client/node name within an Ohai plugin

Tags: chef-infra, ohai-gem

I'm trying to access `node.name` from a custom Ohai plugin. This doesn't seem to be available by default.

It is possible to grab the `hostname` by depending on that attribute with `depends 'hostname'`, but this value may not always match that of `node.name` in my situation.

How can I access the `node.name` from a custom Ohai plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. Ohai can run outside of the context of Chef, so it doesn't know anything about Chef-specific data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was able to work around this by passing the `node.name` in as a variable to the plugin template.